# Talend: configuration dimension time error in tOracleOutput

Tags: talend

I still have this problem

```
Exception in component tOracleOutput_1
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
```

Comment: third image is missing

Comment: What's the error-message? What did you already try? Can you give us  some additional information?

Comment: Exécution en erreur :Échec de la génération du code.
[org.eclipse.emf.codegen.jet.JETException: InvocationTargetException in etlolympictemps job]
Job etlolympictemps terminé à 13:01 23/08/2017. [Code sortie=0]

Answer (score 0):

I have had this as well. What usually helps is restarting Talend or restarting the computer.

If that doesn't help, *there is something wrong with the job*. Then I check every schema, every connection, every `tMap`, every item in the job if there is an error which Talend doesn't show to me.

To check if the code generation system works, you can always click on the `Code` tab and see if something comes up.

**EDIT**

An error ORA-00904 comes up. This leads to the suggestion that a column is named wrongly as seen here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129641/ora-00904-error-while-querying-the-oracle-database-table

> To avoid ORA-00904, column names must
>
> - begin with a letter.
> - consist only of alphanumeric and the special characters ($_#); other characters need double quotation marks around them.
> - be less than or equal to thirty characters.

Comment: Exception in component tOracleOutput_1
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)

Answer (score 0):

There is some currupt code in your job. What you can do is first check is there any code generated for this job. if not try removing each component/disable and run and see if the error persist or not